# Sprite won't animate when ball moves left

Tags: c++, graphics, animation

I'm using SFML 2.1. My program is a simple program of a bouncing ball. When I move right, the ball's animation's frames loop just fine, but when source.y = 0 and I move the ball left, it won't loop. Can anyone see why?

tBall is the texture of the full sprite sheet. Frame.x and frame.y is the size of each frame I take from the sprite sheet. And source.x and source.y are the coordinates within the sprite sheet.

```
frameCounter += frameSpeed * frameClock.restart().asSeconds();
    if (frameCounter >= switchFrame)
    {
        frameCounter = 0;

        //Moving Right
        if (velocity.x < 0)
            source.y += (frame.y * Right);
        //Loop
        if (source.y > tBall.getSize().y - frame.y)
            source.y = 0;

        //Moving Left
        if (velocity.x > 0)
            source.y += (frame.y * Left);
        //Loop
        if (source.y < 0)
            source.y = (tBall.getSize().y - frame.y);
    }

    std::cout << source.y << std::endl;
    ball.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(source.x, source.y, frame.x, frame.y));
```

Sorry if this is a silly overlook.
Thanks in advance!

ps. This is my first question, so please comment if I wrote too much, too little, too vague etc.

EDIT: Left = 1, Right = -1

Comment: And right and left are?

Comment: What do you do when x or y are equal to zero? You does not perform any action for zero values. You should use <= or >=

Comment: Thank you! using greater/less than or equal to fixed it